# Using session in django

Tags: python, django, session

I want to use session in django. Here is my code:

view.py

```
def function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax:
        action = request.POST['action']

        if action == 'check':
            if request.session.get('username', ''):
                print 'yes'
                print request.session['username']
            else:
                print 'no'
                request.session['username'] = 'John'
    return HttpResponse('')
```

The result of function always is `no`.
How to fix it?

Comment: What will request.session print ?

Comment: Have you set username in session before trying to use it? Or you just need to check user is logged in or not?

Comment: `request.is_ajax` should be `request.is_ajax()`